# GridView convert 'Y' or 'N' into checkbox.checked on ItemTemplate field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView below that will show some text and provide a checkbox.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="surveyTableTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSurveyID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "survey_id") %>' />                
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="URL">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="surveyURL" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Used">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="surveyUsed" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>            
    </asp:GridView>
```

I have a simple class which is bound to the GridView. This is populated from a SQL stored procedure.

```
    public class surveyURL 
    {
        public int survey_id { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string used { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I take the information from 'used' which is NCHAR(1) 'Y' or 'N' and turn that into a checkbox.checked result where 'used' = 'Y'

This is what I am currently doing in C#, this is enough to populate the hiddenfield and first template field. I don't know how to proceed for the checkbox.

```
    var test = cn.Query<surveyURL>("sp_create_url", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    surveyTableTest.DataSource = test;
    surveyTableTest.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why not to declare "string used" as "bool used"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Checked` property of CheckBox control and use the [C# Conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) like this:-

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="surveyUsed" runat="server" 
              Checked='<%# Eval("used").ToString() == "Y" ? true: false %>' />
```